# How to handle an event in classes typescript?

Tags: typescript

I need to handle an event and get its parentNode. But, I get an error: 'Property 'parentNode' does not exist on type 'TodoList'

I have tried to use this.parentNode, but still get an error

```
class TodoList {
    constructor() {
        const checkbox: HTMLElement = 
        todoItem.querySelector('.checkbox');
        checkbox.addEventListener('change', this.toggleTodoItem);
}

    toggleTodoItem(): void {
      let node = this.parentNode;
      node.classList.toggle('completed'); 
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `TodoList` class simply does not contain an instance property named `parentNode`, this is why you get the error. Instead, do you want to code something like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/PTAEBcHsBNISXAUwLagJYGdQEMDGvEMM0AjAG0VADMAnSVDexAdwAtEbK0A7UAT0gBXGqFwxEAKGiJcZbJ1GRuGcBBjwkyAFygAEgBUAsgBkAohWSJu4CRNnYiofeuOZVAbwmhvoAA400ADdsJFF2XABrEkgADwA5cR0DE3MUKxsvHzFlcBpBXCgaAAoASlBPH0rFHNBkbD4SRABhcKjYhOlQAF41WAQUADoAR0EOPgBlRAoCyBoAHmSzC3SAPiKAcgHcVuiY9ZKAbkyq9CpQIrqG5p328TKKk6rwVkwtm-jxbtr6xpaZNo+0mOj28z1e23+uw6iAG2Gg0FMgXSrhUVg4G222G4AHNEOsADQQF4YAZQbHYijOPqaQ7AyoAX1AUwwlGedGYoG4LFAphodGKACJUpZrJzIKoqEJuNABgKSsD6bZKmSKYgqRoUKUdIFIGhoOU6T4QDgiIJkDxsfwhLVEFiiZRfPJ0qBIGcIZFdmLOiQ+KAAAZgkmOzjWaF+9C8DDYZC+CiG7zG3AOVTcT7sTiExpJwQsvxO0OfWCEbjrVSsbBIznydmIfXgPi+SQgigpz49QNvSG3aQDYPpaEmvRGJZpUUAH05gjIZCOINTnQAZAuvTD7EQUeBSZByRQMfRY4gkNB9rOfPSjvSgA)?

```
// todoItem is accessible from somewhere in your code
declare const todoItem: HTMLElement

class TodoList {
    private checkboxNode: HTMLElement

    constructor() {
        const maybeCheckboxNode = todoItem.querySelector<HTMLElement>('.checkbox');
        if (maybeCheckboxNode) {
            this.checkboxNode = maybeCheckboxNode
            this.checkboxNode.addEventListener('change', this.toggleTodoItem);
        } else throw new Error("Element not found.")
    }

    toggleTodoItem(): void {
        // assuming you mean the parent of checkbox node by `this.parentNode` in sample
        // cast node here, because parentNode doesn't have narrowed type
        let node = this.checkboxNode.parentNode as HTMLElement | null;
        node && node.classList.toggle('completed');
    };
}
```